# Display multiple images in preview

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this form where I can select multiple images and preview the selected images before submitting the form. But only 1 image is being displayed. I want to display all the selected images. Please help.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="newstatus" runat="server">
    <div style="display: inline-flex">
      <div style="width: 160px">
        <input type="file" name="file-5[]" id="file-5" class="inputfile inputfile-4" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
        <label for="file-5">
        <span style="display: none;">Choose a file&hellip;</span></label>
        <img id="status-img" src="#" alt="" width="150" height="150" /><br />
      <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post" class="post-btn" id="submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#status-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('.removeimg').fadeIn();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#file-5").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
</script>
```

Comment: that's 'cause you're changing the same image's src attribute here `$('#status-img').attr('src', e.target.result);` you have to append another img with the new url for its src

Comment: If I select 8 images then I want to display all 8 images. How can I do that?

Comment: A code FIDDLE example will do..

Comment: as I said, you have to loop through the selected images and append new img elements to the inner div.

Comment: man.. i got u.. but how to do it? I am weak in javascript... can u show me how to do it?

Comment: Please check this link:-https://www.formget.com/upload-multiple-images-using-php-and-jquery/

Comment: i want display images with my code...help will be appreciated in modifying my code.. thanks @Raziasultana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop the number of selected images and play with the data.

HTML CODE:
Add preview div.

```
<div id="imgs"></div>
```

JS Code :

```
 $("#file-5").on('change',function() {
 var fileList = this.files; 
 for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
 {
      //get a blob 
      var t = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      var objectUrl = t.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
      $('#imgs').append('<img src="' + objectUrl + '" />');

      j = i+1;
      if(j % 3 == 0)
      {
        $('#imgs').append('<br>');
      }

 }
});
```

Comment: yes it did the job.. thanks buddy.. can u further modify it for if images selected are more than 3 then it will take next line and it will go on... i think one more loop is needed to be added.. please modify it.. thanks buddy.... :)

Comment: Use <br> tag instead of css

Comment: I am accepting your answer.. but still help me @Gowri

Comment: Where you add the `<div id="imgs"></div>` preview code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127269/discussion-between-gowri-and-shubham-jha).

Comment: Where you add the <div id="imgs"></div> preview code.
`<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="imgs"></div>`
Place it just above the closing form tag.